# Python3 - OpenCV & cv2.error: (-215) Unable to show captured image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to using `opencv-3.3.0`, `cv2` & `python3.5`.

But, I can't seem to show image I have captured.

- I read all the documentation.
- I tried all possible answers.
- But, I still unsuccessful.

What am I missing?

## Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("F:/Train/sreen.png")
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## The Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.0\moules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 333 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\IQ_option\OpenCV\run.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:333: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

## The image:

[image: My Code.]

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/bQJTueI)

Comment: Check that the image is loaded correctly. And [edit] the code inside the question

Answer (score 8):

The only reason for this to not work is that the file you are trying here isn't loaded properly in the `imread` command. The loaded image is non existent due to which it says that `size.width` and `size.height` > 0.

You can check if either the file is present in your specified location or not. Also, you might need to use double `\\` while providing the full path of the .png file you want to display. Also, it might be that .png files are not supported here. You may try any other .jpg image file instead and retry. An example would be like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\fakepath\\Pictures\\Messi.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.environ['OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS']=str(2**64)
import cv2
```

Before importing cv2, you should set environ to solve the error. It works for me.

Comment: I think the problem here was that the image path wasn't properly formatted. 
but this solves the problem of running out of memory when opening very large pictures. ( `error: (-215:Assertion failed) pixels <= CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS`)

Answer (score 1):

I previously encountered the same problem. Then I realized that my image file path is misspelled. In my code, an image file was named "note.jpg" and in my directory, it was "note.jpg.jpg" and instead of "j.jpg" I wrote it as "j.png". After recorrecting them, everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in an environment like jupyter with ipython then you have to check if :

1. If the image path is correct
2. If the image is not empty

If you have a correct path and your image is not empty then you have maybe installed many times OpenCv (i had the same problem) and notebook is been confused. The solution is simple.

- Find where does your notebook store its downloads(for me it was C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36....)
- Delete cv2 file and everything related with opencv
- Open a terminal using the one built-in in your notebook  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcXqr.jpg)

-Install opencv-python from scratch by typing : pip install opencv-python
-If its needed add --user at the end of the command so you can act like an admin 
- Reboot your notebook and it should be fine. I had the same problem and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

i got the same mistake.I tried a lot of things to solve the problem.But afterwards i have realised that problem was about the path. ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/savKV.png)Do not use path which has foreign letters)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your file path is correct. I misspelled the file(`img = cv2.imread('Images/ab.png',0)` instead of `img = cv2.imread('Images/abi.png',0)`) and I was getting the same error:

```
.......cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:757: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'.
```

It may be this much simple.